# Get specify parent element id using his class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try get id parent **p** **div** (class mainRow), but my code in console return **undefinied**:

```
<div class="row mainRow" id="someId">
  <div class="selected">
    <p onclick="checkParentId(this)">Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

function checkParentId(element){
  var a = $(element).parent( ".mainRow");
  var b  = $(a).attr("id");
  console.log(b);
}
</script>
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50ev1jzq/

Comment: the parent of your <p> doesnt have class mainRow that is the grandparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `.mainRow` is not a parent of the paragraph, use `.closest`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>parent demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="row mainRow" id="someId">

<div class="selected">
<p onclick="checkParentId(this)">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
 
<script>

function checkParentId(element){
debugger
var a = $(element).closest( ".mainRow" );
var b  = $(a).attr("id");
console.log(b);
}

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `parents()`, because according to the docs:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `parent()` method traverses to the immediate parent of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.
>   This method is similar to `.parents()`, except `.parent()` only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

As others have pointed out, `closest()` could also work. There are some differences tough:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I find sollution, i change **.parent** to **.closest** and code work

```
<div class="row mainRow" id="someId">
  <div class="selected">
    <p onclick="checkParentId(this)">Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

function checkParentId(element){
  var a = $(element).closest( ".mainRow");
  var b  = $(a).attr("id");
  console.log(b);
}
</script>
```